# How to create an instance of a generic class that has a type paramater which extends a static class within its own class?

Tags: java, generics, instance

So, I have a generic class `BinaryTree` that I used as source code that has a type parameter called `Node` (which I normally see as `T`). The class looks something like this:

```
public class BinaryTree<Node extends BinaryTree.BTNode<Node>> {

public static class BTNode<Node extends BTNode<Node>> {
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public Node parent; 
}

public BinaryTree(Node sampleNode) {
    this.sampleNode = sampleNode;
}

//Some methods

}
```

Normally, (with my other generic classes), assuming it passes the type into its constructor, I invoked it by doing this:

```
BinaryTree<Integer> myTree=new BinaryTree<Integer>(Integer.class);
```

But of course this doesn't work as it wants type `Node` which extends `BTNode`. How would I reference a `Node` extending `BTNode` so that I can create an instance of `BinaryTree`?

Comment: Didn't try it but I think you basically can only use BTNode there.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the type parameter of the `BTNode` class a bit, it becomes possible:

```java
class BinaryTree<Node extends BinaryTree.BTNode>
{
    static class BTNode<T> {
        T value;
        public BTNode<T> left;
        public BTNode<T> right;
        public BTNode<T> parent;

        BTNode(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private Node root;

    public BinaryTree(Node node) {
        root = node;
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
class CustomNode extends BinaryTree.BTNode<Integer> {
    CustomNode(Integer value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
BinaryTree<CustomNode> bt = new BinaryTree<>(new CustomNode(10));
```